# Create spaces between check boxes

Tags: c#

I have a checkedlistbox and when i populate it i want to have an empty space between each check box. i can create them with an empty string but the check box is still there. can anyone please help me.

thank you

Comment: Can you show the HTML that is causing the problem?

Comment: Clarify: you want empty space *vertically* between each row that contains a check box?

Comment: Missing some important info. Are you using WPF, ASP, ...?

Comment: @Sohnee, this isn't HTML

Comment: Correct your grammar then explain the problem in detail.

Comment: The first question that I would ask is why you need a space between elements.  There may be a better way to solve that problem.  The only way I can think of to include spaces between elements in a CheckedListBox is to implement a custom version of the control yourself, or possibly override the paint method, neither of which I'd recommend.

Comment: @JYelton - well, the question really could tell us if it's ASP.NET, WPF or WinForms. There just isn't enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using .NET C# winforms...

You can inherit this control, and override the property `.ItemHeight` as follows:

```
private class OverriddenCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    public override int ItemHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Place one of these controls on your form, and set the property to a height that suits the amount of space you desire. (If you want it to show up in the toolbox you'll need to create it as a user control.) Here is an example:

```
OverriddenCheckedListBox ochkListBox = new OverriddenCheckedListBox();
ochkListBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
ochkListBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
ochkListBox.Items.Add("Alpha");
ochkListBox.Items.Add("Beta");
ochkListBox.Items.Add("Charlie");
ochkListBox.Items.Add("Delta");
ochkListBox.Items.Add("Epsilon");
ochkListBox.ItemHeight = 30; // This is your row height
this.Controls.Add(ochkListBox);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but this creates a new checkedlistbox, is there a way i can make them show up on the checkedlistbox i created? also the height property does not seem to work.

Comment: I want to add empty spaces vertically in between check boxes.